# MCMC Sampler not Converging for Particular Function

Tags: matlab, markov-chain-montecarlo

I've written some MCMC code which I thought worked, but for more complicated functions it breaks down. The MCMC algorithm I am using, uses a simple Metropolis algorithm.

In the code which I will attach below, when I use:

```
f = @(x1,x2) [1,2];   % A simple function which only spits out [1,2]
```

Everything converges (i.e. my random walks converge to a mean). This is shown in my image below:

[image: When the simple function is used]

However when I use the more complicated function instead:

```
f = @(x1,x2) x1.^2 + x2.^2 + 20;  % A nonlinearity (when this is used MCMC can't converge)
```

my random walks go nowhere. To clarify these are the diagrams I am getting:
[image: When the complicated function is used.]

This is my MATLAB code which I tried to make as easy to follow as I could. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

```
clear all
clc

%% DEFINE THE FIRST FUNCTION (kind of like a likelihood function)
N = 1;
sigma_ML = 0.03;   
cov_ML = eye(2)*sigma_ML;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
f = @(x1,x2) x1.^2 + x2.^2 + 20;  % A nonlinearity (when this is used MCMC can't converge)
% f = @(x1,x2) [1,2];          % A simple function which only spits out [1,2] 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% My f(x1,x2) is used in p2 below:
p2 = @(x1,x2) 1./(2*pi*det(cov_ML))^(N/2) * ...
              exp( -1/2*(f(x1,x2) - [x1,x2])*inv(cov_ML)*(f(x1,x2) - [x1,x2])' );



%% DEFINE ANOTHER FUNCTION (basically like a prior function)
sigma_a = 1;
sigma_b = 1;
mu_a = 10;
mu_b = -20;
p1 = @(x1,x2) (1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma_a^2))*exp(-1/(2*sigma_a^2)*(x1-mu_a).^2))...
        .*(1/sqrt((2*pi*sigma_b^2))*exp(-1/(2*sigma_b^2)*(x2-mu_b).^2));    



%% MULTIPLY THE PRIOR AND LIKELIHOODS TOGETHER
p = @(x1,x2) p1(x1,x2).*p2(x1,x2);  % This is the function I will be using in my MCMC



%% INITIALISE VARIABLES
nSamples = 500000;
t = 1;      % To keep track of how many total MCMC steps have been taken
idx = 2;    % To keep track of how many successful MCMC steps have been taken
x(1,:) = randn(1,2)+10;    % To start the algorithm




%% RUN MCMC SAMPLER
while t < nSamples
    t = t + 1;

    % SAMPLE FROM PROPOSAL (2D multivariate normal)
    xStar = mvnrnd(x(idx-1,:),eye(2));


    % CALCULATE THE M-H ACCEPTANCE PROBABILITY
    alpha(t) = min([1, p(xStar(1),xStar(2))/p(x(idx-1,1),x(idx-1,2))]);

    % ACCEPT OR REJECT?
    u = rand;
    if u < alpha(t)
        x(idx,:) = xStar;
        idx = idx + 1;
    else
        x(idx,:) = x(idx-1,:);
    end

    if(mod(t,10000)==0)
        fprintf('%d / %d\n',t,nSamples);
    end
end
```

Something I have noticed is that when I use the more complicated f(x1,x2) my MCMC algorithm accepts basically everything (my alpha is almost always unity). However, with my simpler f(x1,x2) = [1,2] the alpha does very (so some cases are accepted, some other ones are rejected) - which makes sense to me.

Thanks for your help!!!

P.S. You can copy-paste my code directly into MATLAB it is perfectly runnable as is.

EDIT/UPDATE: The same behviour happens even without the prior, 'p1(x1,x2)' function. So if you just let p = @(x1,x2) p2(x1,x2) I still get a non-convergence issue, so fundamentally p2(x1,x2) is causing issues, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've got an underflow issue.

The expression
    `exp( -1/2*(f(x1,x2) - [x1,x2])*inv(cov_ML)*(f(x1,x2) - [x1,x2])' )` will evaluate to zero as the quantity inside `exp()` tends towards `-Inf`. When you divide by zero Matlab returns a `NaN` and `min([1,NaN])` will return a `1`. That's why `alpha` consistently takes a value of `1`.

Do you need to exponentiate that expression? One potential fix is just to leave the interior expression as is, without the `exp()`. Unless this breaks what you're trying to do (tbh, I don't really understand what all you have going on in your likelihood function).

The other potential issue is that your function
`f = @(x1,x2) x1.^2 + x2.^2 + 20` only returns one value. Did you mean to have `f = @(x1,x2) [x1.^2, x2.^2] + 20`?

Comment: Yup my Likelihood function started out as a Likelihood function but I played around with it a bit so it's not 100% one any more.




But I disagree with the f = @(x1,x2) x1.^2 + x2.^2 + 20 expression only producing one value. When I just put that into the matlab command window, this function doesn't only return one value. i.e. f(1,1) returns something different to f(5,8). Is this what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it returns a scalar, rather than an array.  Your simple function that works returns a two-element array.  Maybe this doesn't matter, though.

Comment: Oh that is a good pick up. Lucky for me Matlab handles matrices in a way which didn't really effect which option I chose.